# Why is there a "a" before lack in one case and not in the other?

Tags: articles

> I have **a lack** of imagination.

> The party was bonkers, for **lack** of a better word.

I was having a discussion with a friend and some of the points raised were:

1. In the second sentence, "for lack of a better word" is an object complement.
2. There are two ways in which "lack" can be used. Either as a noun or a verb. In case (1) the noun form of the word is used.
3. It's not "for a lack of a better word" and just "for lack of a better word" because "for" already implies an indefinite article.

I wasn't very satisfied with this argument so I posit two questions:

1. Why is there no "a" before "lack" in "for lack of a better word" (or any similar phrases for that matter ex. for lack of trying, for want....)
2. Are discussion points 1 and 3 correct? i.e. "for lack of a better word" is an object complement and that it lacks a definite article because "for" already implies it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers makes a lot of sense. What about question #2? and just so i am clear here "for lack of a better term/word" is the idiomatic usage and not the one with "the" right?

Comment: I don't really know or care exactly what you or anyone else defines as an "object complement". I speak and write English perfectly well without ever having learned such things (*and* I've got a degree in English Language & Literature! :). But I have to say your point about *it lacks a definite article because "for" already implies it* doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: (In which context, note exclamatory ***For the love of God / Pete / Mike**!*, which would almost never occur without the definite article.)

Comment: There's a load of more or less idiomatic expressions of this form, which don't take an article, and can't be varied; and in some cases have a meaning not deducible from the normal sense of the words: _in need of_, _in spite of_, _in aid of_, _with reference to_, _with regard to_, _by dint of_, _in deference to_.

Answer (score 1):

Posting FumbleFingers's lightly edited comments here as an answer:

> There is no "a" before "lack" in "for lack of a better word" because if we were going to include an article there, it would be the definite article. Note that for [the] lack of a better word is semantically and syntactically identical to "in the absence of a better word" (where "the" is idiomatically required)
>
> There's no difference between "for lack of a better word" and "for the lack of a better word". It's just a matter of what's become idiomatically established.

Answer (score 0):

- a lack of imagination is an x of y.
- a harbinger of truth
- a sign of wealth
- a letter of credit
- a man of peace

The a article denotes something in general; and the nouns are all mass nouns or abstract nouns or a given expression (letter of credit).

Now, **lack** can function as an abstract noun:

- Lack of sleep can make you sick.
- Lack of money must mean something.

But, you can also use: A lack of sleep can make you sick.

However, abstract nouns do not need an  **a** after for.*

- **For peace in our times**, a lot of effort must be made.
- **For imagination** to work, it needs a place to grow.
- He did poorly on the exam **for lack of imagination**.

However, when we qualify that imagination or lack, watch what happens:

- He was not punished for **a** singular lack of imagination
- They did not lose due to **a** huge lack of will power